# Powershell executed within .csproj and running elevated could not access host file

Tags: powershell

Situation:
I am running Visual Studio as administrator.
I use the script to initialize my solution. One of the initialization tasks is to set host file entries.
I execute a powershell script in the csproj file during the build process in the target BeforeBuild:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <InitScriptPath Condition=" '$(InitScriptPath)' == '' ">$(SolutionDir)Scripts\InitKentico.ps1</InitScriptPath>
  <KenticoVersion Condition=" '$(KenticoVersion)' == '' ">10.0.0</KenticoVersion>
  <KenticoProjectName Condition=" '$(KenticoProjectName)' == '' ">Kentico10WebAppDemo</KenticoProjectName>
  <KenticoWebsiteBinding Condition=" '$(KenticoWebsiteBinding)' == '' ">local.kentico10webappdemo.com</KenticoWebsiteBinding>
  <InitScriptCommand Condition=" '$(InitScriptCommand)' == '' ">%SystemRoot%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&amp; { &amp;'$(InitScriptPath)' '$(ProjectDir)' '$(SolutionDir)' '$(KenticoVersion)' '$(KenticoProjectName)' '$(KenticoWebsiteBinding)'; exit $lastexitcode }"</InitScriptCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="Running Init PowerShell Script: $(InitScriptPath) with command $(InitScriptCommand)" Importance="high" />
<Exec Command="$(InitScriptCommand)" />
```

I check within my powershell if the script is executed as administrator:

```
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

if (-not($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))) {          
    Write-Host "Must be executed as administrator!"
    exit 1
}
```

I use the following script to edit the host file:

```
$file = Join-Path -Path $($env:windir) -ChildPath "system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
$data = Get-Content -Path $file
$entriesBlockHeader = "### MyWebsite ###";
$hostEntry1 = "127.0.0.1`tmy-website.com"
$hostEntry2 = "127.0.0.1`twww.my-website.com"
$entriesBlock = [System.Environment]::NewLine + $entriesBlockHeader
$entriesBlock = $entriesBlock + [System.Environment]::NewLine + $hostEntry1            
$entriesBlock = $entriesBlock + [System.Environment]::NewLine + $hostEntry2
$data = $data + $entriesBlock            
$data | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

My Issue:
When it comes to change the host file, the script throws an exception because permissions are denied.
I do not understand why this happens. The script is executed as administrator, so it should have the needed permissions.
When I execute the script in the Powershell ISE (as administrator) it works like a charm. Only if executed from the csproj file in Visual Studio (as administrator) it is not working.